# Javascript class passing parameters

Tags: javascript

I have been creating several classes but I never had any that needed parameters on the class itself.

The following code works perfectly.

```
$(function()
{
   search.anotherFunction('a', 'b');
});

search = function()
{

   this.anotherFunction = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // do whatever
   };

   var public = { anotherFunction: anotherFunction }  

   return public;
}();
```

But now I would like to pass parameters inside `search` in order to avoid passing the same parameters to all the functions.

```
$(function()
{
   search('front/file.php').anotherFunction('a', 'b');
});

search = function(url)
{

   this.anotherFunction = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // use here the 'url' parameter
   };

   this.anotherFunctionB = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // use here the 'url' parameter
   };

   var public = { anotherFunction: anotherFunction,
                  anotherFunctionB: anotherFunctionB }  

   return public;
}();
```

This doesn't work and the console outputs the error.

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

It means that `search` isn't a function but yes a class name and therefore can't receive params?

Comment: `anotherFunction: anotherFunction` should be `anotherFunction: this.anotherFunction`. Same goes for `anotherFunctionB`.

Comment: did you try like this { anotherFunction: this.anotherFunction,
                  anotherFunctionB: this.anotherFunctionB }

Comment: Guys the problem isn't the functions itself, is passing parameters to the class.

Comment: Curious as to why you've put that in a jQuery document.ready handler? Sometimes just using jQuery's plugin/widget factories is easier !

Comment: @adeneo just to use as an example. In my real code I call the class inside a `onClick` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, the way you're creating your "classes" is incorrect, and ends up creating global variables: Inside the call to your anonymous function, because of the way you call it, `this` will refer to the global object*, so `this.anotherFunction = ...` will create a global variable called `anotherFunction`, because properties on the global object are global variables.

If you want to keep using your current pattern with minimal changes, then don't use `this.xyz = ...` with your functions, use `var` instead:

```
var search = function()
{
   var anotherFunction = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // do whatever
   };

   var public = { anotherFunction: anotherFunction }  

   return public;
}();
```

Also note that you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring `search`; I've added a `var` to declare it.

Your second example, with the changes above, would work if you *didn't* call the outermost function and just assigned the function to the `search` variable, then called it later:

```
var search = function(url)
{

   var anotherFunction = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // use here the 'url' parameter
   };

   var anotherFunctionB = function(param1, param2)
   {
      // use here the 'url' parameter
   };

   var public = { anotherFunction: anotherFunction,
                  anotherFunctionB: anotherFunctionB }  

   return public;
}; // <== Note, no () here
```

Now `search` refers to a function, which we can call like this:

```
var x = search("http://example.com");
x.anotherFunction(...); // Will have access to the URL
```

---

* Why does `this` refer to the global object when you call your anonymous function? Because you call it without doing anything to set `this` to something else, and you're using loose mode. (I know you're using loose mode because if you were using strict mode, `this` would be `undefined` and so `this.anotherFunction = ...` would fail.)

---

Side note: I would recommend you stop using `public` as a variable name, as it's a [future reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1.2) and has been since at least ES3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript closures here. Check out the below approach:

```
search = function()
{
    return function (url) {
       this.anotherFunction = function(param1, param2)
       {
          // use here the 'url' parameter
       };

       this.anotherFunctionB = function(param1, param2)
       {
          // use here the 'url' parameter
       };

       var public = { anotherFunction: anotherFunction,
                      anotherFunctionB: anotherFunctionB }  

       return public;
    }
}();

search('front/file.php').anotherFunction('a', 'b');
```

Comment: He/she *could* do it like that (other than the `this` problem I mentioned in my answer, which is also present above), but it's got an unnecessary level of nesting. You don't need the outer function at all.

Comment: the problem of `this` can definitely be rectified by the approach you mentioned. But since @Linesofcode of code mentioned to pass another param in Search I provided the option to do so through this approach